# SQL query to search several rows with same id field but different parameter field

Tags: php, sql, database, filter

I feel that this should be simple, but I'm stuck. This is what I have in my DB

```
id   field_value
----------------
41   Blue
42   Blue
43   Blue
43   Sweet
46   Blue   
47   Sweet
```

I need to select fields that only have `$colour = blue AND $taste = sweet`. 
Basically I need to get the id of 43 because it has both Blue and Sweet. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You would usually test it like this:

```
select id
  from table1
 where field_value in ('Blue', 'Sweet')
 group by id
having count (distinct field_value) = 2
```

`= 2` is number of items in `in ()` list.

[Check out the test @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d3ed2/2).

Comment: the query worked well in the sql fiddle, but gives me an error in the phpMyAdmin. Can it be sql version problem or smth?

Comment: @Julia this is standard Sql. But MySql - God bless its eccentric soul - dislikes a blank after a function. It should be fine after you remove blank after count.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly; Something like this:

```
$colour = (!isset($_GET['colour']) || empty($_GET['colour'])) ? '' : $_GET['colour'];
$taste = (!isset($_GET['taste']) || empty($_GET['taste'])) ? '' : $_GET['taste'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (parameter = '$colour') AND (parameter = '$taste')";
```

Comment: Returns 0 rows with AND. When I use OR it finds the rows, but in that case having 2 or more parameters widens the search result, and what I need is to narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Can you have a look at my edited post. I figured out how to deal with empty values, but I can't still get it to find results with more than 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a query within a query. Something like;

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE field_value = 'Blue'
AND
id IN (SELECT id
    FROM table
    WHERE field_value = 'Sweet')
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks! looks like what I need. Is there a way to make it with more than 2 variables?

Comment: You can throw in an AND in the CASE statement or add more WHEN choices.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I am a bit confused how case works. Maybe it can be done easier. Here is an actual table after I selected `field_value=Blru OR field_value=Sweet`
`id field_valu
41  Blue
42  Blue
43  Blue
43  Sweet
46  Blue 
47  Sweet`
You can see that only id 43 has both Blue and Sweet. When I run query with AND it shows nothing. How do I select only that 43 id?

Comment: OK, I think I get it now. Is the edited query above what you are after?